# pandas: grouping by a categorical feature, then dropping all groups that deviate from having just one 'true' entry for a binary feature

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe where the entries can be grouped by the value of a particular categorical feature.  Within these groups, there should be only one entry which is true ('1') for another binary categorical feature; however some groups contain two or zero such entries.  I wish to drop all the rows/entries in these anomolous groups from the dataframe.

I'm trying for something like the below (which I'm aware is hopelessly wrong - I'm pretty green though...)

```
grouped = df.groupby('Categorical_Column')
df_new = df.drop(grouped[((grouped['BinaryFeature'] == 1).agg(np.sum)) != 1])
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Do you have sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df_new = df.groupby('Categorical_Column')['BinaryFeature'].filter(lambda x: x.sum() != 1)
```

Or to get all the columns back:

```
df_new = df.groupby('Categorical_Column').filter(lambda x: x['BinaryFeature'].sum() != 1)
```

And to get the other records:

```
df_new = df.groupby('Categorical_Column')['BinaryFeature'].filter(lambda x: x.sum() == 1)
```

Or to get all the columns back:

```
df_new = df.groupby('Categorical_Column').filter(lambda x: x['BinaryFeature'].sum() == 1)
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, thanks so much! The only change I've needed to make is x.sum() == 1 to drop the anomalous rows as opposed to selecting them. I have another question now though - how do I transform df_new here back into a version of the original dataframe (i.e. with all original columns - there are actually many other features in the dataset)? As it is it currently consists of just the BinaryFeature alone.

Comment: @IanF See edit and that will return all the columns back.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!  I only wish I'd come on here to ask for help earlier!  Much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome.  However, next time I would advise you give a sample of your input data, your code like you did here and what you expect.  That helps the others help you quicker. :-).  When you have time read this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).